# How often do siege creeps spawn?

Tags: dota-2

In Dota 2, you have creeps come out in waves that fight against the other team's creeps. Sometimes siege creeps (a.k.a. catapults) will also be spawned.

How often do siege creeps spawn as part of a creep wave?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Siege creeps spawn every 7th wave, starting at 3:00 (the 7th wave). At 45:00 into the game, each wave with a siege creep will instead spawn 2 siege creeps.

Because the first wave spawns at 0:00, the first siege creep is at 3:00, then every 3:30 afterwards.

**Additional Information**

Each wave will spawn an additional melee creep at 15:00, 30:00 and 45:00. At 45:00, each wave will spawn an additional ranged creep.

Thus after 45:00, each wave will spawn 6 melee creeps, 2 ranged creeps and 0 or 2 siege creeps (siege creeps still only spawn on every 7th wave).

Melee and ranged creeps get stronger (damage and health) every 7:30, maxing out at 3:45:00. When you destroy all of an enemy's barracks, the creeps instantly reach maximum strength, and siege creeps get a damage boost.

**[Source](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Creeps#Mechanics)**

Comment: "When you destroy all of an enemy's barracks, the creeps instantly reach maximum strength" – whose creeps? Yours or the enemy's?

Comment: @Dacio Yours. Yep, the enemy barracks are stopping your creeps being strong!

Comment: That's why going for barracks is a viable option instead of trying to attack the towers in front of the ancient